# Is this legal C++ code?

Tags: c++, standards

I'm interested in answers citing a concrete passage in the standard, not just general opinions.

```
template <class T> struct wrapped
{
       wrapped(const T&) {}
};

template <class T> wrapped<T> wrappit(const T& x)
{
       return wrapped<T>(x);
}

template <class T> int run_function(const T& x, bool wrapped)
{
       if (wrapped) {
               return 0;
       } else {
               return run_function(wrappit(x), true) + 1;
       }
}

int main()
{
       const int result = run_function(0.5, false);
       return result;
}
```

Comment: What is this supposed to do? All it does is make `main` return 1 in a roundabout way.

Comment: What makes you think it is illegal C++? Despite the fact that infinitive instantiation depth is most likely to kill a stupid compiler? I mean, does "int main() {}" a legal C++ code? Please find me a passage in a standard about it.

Comment: Is this a question about the definition of the word "legal"? I guess the compiler will recursively wrap T in `wrapped<wrapped<wrapped<...`, so I guess there's no way it can compile.

Comment: What the hell is going on here? Running this through Visual Studio I get an endless stream of `warning C4503: 'wrapped<T>' : decorated name length exceeded, name was truncated`

Comment: it also makes mingw's compiler go into an infinite loop...

Comment: Is the question whether you can call a template function with 1 parameter from the same template function with a different type?

Comment: Maybe he wants to ask if syntactic or semantic correct code which causes an infinite loop while compiling is illegal?

Comment: Similar question: Is this legal? `template <unsigned int N> void foo() { foo<N+1>(); } int main() { foo<0>(); }`

Comment: @Joel Actually, I encountered this situation writing production code (my bad). This is not a contrived example. If you can't answer this question, at least don't insult me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From 14.7.1(15):

> The result of an inﬁnite recursion in instantiation is undefined.

---

Regarding your code: You cannot do static conditionals with `if`. Instead, you'll need some sort of functional approach, and partial specialization:

```
template <typename T, bool> struct run_function;
template <typename T> struct run_function<T, true>
{
    static int go(T const & x) { return 0; }
};
template <typename T> struct run_function<T, false>
{
    static int go(T const & x)
    { return 1 + run_function<T, true>::go(wrappit(x)); }
};
```

Now there's no more infinite recursion, because the two branches use *different* templates which eventually do not instantiate further templates.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but I need to set the bool switch at runtime. The correct way to fix it is to call a different function from the first one.

Answer (score 5):

A conforming implementation may reject this code.  See Annex B of the Standard.

Your implementation is supposed to include certain limits in its documentation, these include:

- Recursively nested template instantiations

Comment: Ben, I think every compiler will reject it either because of the recursive nested instantiation or because they will crash or stuck in infinitive loop until they run out of memory and crash :-D

Comment: @Vlad: A sufficiently smart optimizer could break the infinite recursion.

Comment: @VladLazarenko On my box, Cygwin gcc reports an error. At least it doesn't enter in an infinite loop.